# how to sum the all column and all nulls get display into one (NA) in sql with out using replace

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
cid c2id
1   null
1   null
1   null
null    1
null    2
null    3
 2   null
 3   null
null  4
null  2
```

output:-

```
cid c2id
3   NA
NA  6
5   NA
NA  6
```

if add any one record it will also add and give out put like same

Answer (score 0):

use two queries, one to sum, other to count nulls, then union them. There is no command which does it at once.

Comment: this query is using select coalesce(cast(sum(cid) as varchar(100)),'na')  , coalesce(cast(sum(ccid) as varchar(100)),'na')  from tbl group by cid

Comment: in feature inset any records into table that one also be add into the values.display like above output.

Comment: performance wise you will do great with using for loops, because you are considering your sql table to be "ordered"... why don't you make one additional column with the id (first 3 rows id 1, another 3 rows id 2, another 2 rows id 3, last 2 rows id 4), to make your life easier? It would be also much more understandable by anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way that you could try

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR, SUM(cid) OVER(PARTITION BY cid)), 'NA') cid,
       ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR, SUM(c2id) OVER(PARTITION BY cid)), 'NA') c2id
FROM <table_name>;
```

Result :

```
cid c2id
3   NA
NA  6
```

Comment: Changing the question after you have asked it is rude. It can invalidate answers which in turn can attract downvotes

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have ID as Identity primary key column in your table for the order.

**Query**:

```
; WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *,
        CASE WHEN C2id IS NULL
                THEN (SELECT top 1 ID FROM cid n WHERE n.c2id IS NOT NULL AND n.ID > CID.ID) 
            WHEN Cid IS NULL
                THEN (SELECT top 1 ID FROM cid n WHERE n.cid IS NOT NULL AND n.ID > CID.ID) 
        END AS NextID
    FROM CID
)
SELECT
    CASE WHEN MIN(c2id) IS NULL THEN SUM(cid) ELSE -1 END AS cid,
    CASE WHEN MIN(cid) IS NULL THEN SUM(c2id) ELSE -1 END AS c2id   
FROM CTE
GROUP BY NextID
ORDER BY CASE WHEN NEXTID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, NextID
```

**Sample Output**:

```
    cid c2id
    3   -1
   -1   6
    5   -1
   -1   6
```

You can replace -1 with NA. It calculates the next ID for required group and calculates sum in that group.

Please evaluate performance and correctness of query before using it.